# No internet access via wifi, pppoe & pptp

Tags: wireless, networking, vpn

Recently i installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS;

I have a problem with connecting to internet via pptp client connection. I will connect to the wireless connection of my college then pppoe connection and then pptp for internet access.

I connect to wifi and pppoe successfully that that is the only way I can get access to the college website. Then I connect to pptp but I lost all my internet access (`ping` & browse);

This is my `ifconfig` result:

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:192.168.11.37  P-t-P:192.168.11.10  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1488  Metric:1
      RX packets:297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:23812 (23.8 KB)  TX bytes:26959 (26.9 KB)

ppp1      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:176.102.250.25  P-t-P:176.102.224.55  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1408  Metric:1
      RX packets:169 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:173 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:10241 (10.2 KB)  TX bytes:10541 (10.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:7c:8f:3b:f0:ee  
      inet addr:192.168.193.154  Bcast:192.168.193.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::227c:8fff:fe3b:f0ee/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:13292 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2158036 (2.1 MB)  TX bytes:160543 (160.5 KB)
```

and my `route -n` result:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp1
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
176.102.224.55  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp1
192.168.11.10   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.100.55  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.193.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

ppp0 is for pppoe, ppp1 for pptp and wlan0 is for my wireless

My `syslog` shows:

```
Aug  2 12:34:17 fman-Q1585M avahi-daemon[861]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.193.154.
Aug  2 12:34:17 fman-Q1585M avahi-daemon[861]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug  2 12:34:17 fman-Q1585M avahi-daemon[861]: Registering new address record for 192.168.193.154 on wlan0.IPv4.
Aug  2 12:34:17 fman-Q1585M kernel: [  940.384157] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Aug  2 12:35:02 fman-Q1585M kernel: [  984.933056] wlan0: authenticate with 00:15:6d:f8:09:6d
Aug  2 12:35:02 fman-Q1585M kernel: [  984.953053] wlan0: send auth to 00:15:6d:f8:09:6d (try 1/3)
Aug  2 12:35:02 fman-Q1585M kernel: [  984.956477] wlan0: authenticated
Aug  2 12:35:02 fman-Q1585M kernel: [  984.968881] wlan0: associate with 00:15:6d:f8:09:6d (try 1/3)
Aug  2 12:35:02 fman-Q1585M kernel: [  984.977656] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:15:6d:f8:09:6d (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=7)
Aug  2 12:35:02 fman-Q1585M kernel: [  984.978665] wlan0: associated
Aug  2 12:35:02 fman-Q1585M kernel: [  984.978968] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Aug  2 12:35:04 fman-Q1585M avahi-daemon[861]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::227c:8fff:fe3b:f0ee.
Aug  2 12:35:04 fman-Q1585M avahi-daemon[861]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Aug  2 12:35:04 fman-Q1585M avahi-daemon[861]: Registering new address record for fe80::227c:8fff:fe3b:f0ee on wlan0.*.
Aug  2 12:35:33 fman-Q1585M dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.193.154 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Aug  2 12:35:33 fman-Q1585M dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.193.154 from 192.168.189.2
Aug  2 12:35:33 fman-Q1585M dhclient: bound to 192.168.193.154 -- renewal in 33990 seconds.
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2908]: Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: PPP session is 1513
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: Connected to d4:ca:6d:89:1d:fa via interface wlan0
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: Using interface ppp0
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: Connect: ppp0 <--> wlan0
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M NetworkManager[866]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M NetworkManager[866]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: Remote message: Login ok
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: PAP authentication succeeded
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: peer from calling number D4:CA:6D:89:1D:FA authorized
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: replacing old default route to wlan0 [192.168.193.10]
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: local  IP address 192.168.11.77
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: remote IP address 192.168.11.10
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: primary   DNS address 192.168.100.6
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: CCP terminated by peer (No compression negotiated^@)
Aug  2 12:36:06 fman-Q1585M pppd[2910]: Compression disabled by peer.
Aug  2 12:36:26 fman-Q1585M pppd[2948]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Aug  2 12:36:26 fman-Q1585M pppd[2948]: Using interface ppp1
Aug  2 12:36:26 fman-Q1585M pppd[2948]: Connect: ppp1 <--> /dev/pts/1
Aug  2 12:36:26 fman-Q1585M NetworkManager[866]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1)
Aug  2 12:36:26 fman-Q1585M NetworkManager[866]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1): no ifupdown configuration found.
Aug  2 12:36:26 fman-Q1585M pptp[2950]: anon log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Aug  2 12:36:26 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Aug  2 12:36:26 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Aug  2 12:36:26 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Aug  2 12:36:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Aug  2 12:36:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Aug  2 12:36:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 31649).
Aug  2 12:36:28 fman-Q1585M pppd[2948]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Aug  2 12:36:28 fman-Q1585M pppd[2948]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Aug  2 12:36:29 fman-Q1585M pppd[2948]: local  IP address 176.102.250.111
Aug  2 12:36:29 fman-Q1585M pppd[2948]: remote IP address 176.102.224.55
Aug  2 12:37:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug  2 12:38:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug  2 12:39:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug  2 12:40:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug  2 12:41:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug  2 12:42:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug  2 12:43:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug  2 12:44:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug  2 12:45:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug  2 12:46:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug  2 12:46:27 fman-Q1585M pptp[2958]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:679]: no more Echo Reply/Request packets will be reported.
Aug  2 13:17:01 fman-Q1585M CRON[3498]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M pptp[3392]: anon log[pptp_handle_timer:pptp_ctrl.c:1050]: closing control connection due to missing echo reply
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M pptp[3392]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M pptp[3392]: anon log[pptp_conn_close:pptp_ctrl.c:430]: Closing PPTP connection
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M pptp[3392]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 3 'Stop-Control-Connection-Request'
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M pptp[3392]: anon log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M pppd[3382]: Modem hangup
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M pppd[3382]: Connect time 24.0 minutes.
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M pppd[3382]: Sent 909838891 bytes, received 12167 bytes.
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M pppd[3382]: MPPE disabled
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M pppd[3382]: Connection terminated.
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M avahi-daemon[861]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp1.
Aug  2 13:18:15 fman-Q1585M NetworkManager[866]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1)
Aug  2 13:18:16 fman-Q1585M pppd[3382]: Exit.
```